How to count the number of students from each course from the mysql database?
So, I want to make a calculator that will calculate this formula:
Result = No. of Attendance / (No. of Students * No. of School Days) 

but I want the No. of students to be counted automatically by course and strand (different column) from the database.
This is the initial code:
<?php include 'includes/session.php'; ?>
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

  <?php include 'includes/navbar.php'; ?>
  <?php include 'includes/menubar.php'; ?>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Calculator
      </h1>
    </section>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-body">
              <form method="post">
                <label for="D">No. of Attendance:</label>
                <input type="text" id="D" name="D" placeholder="No. of Attendance" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['D']) ? $_POST['D'] : '' ?>"><br>
                <label for="B">No. of Students:</label>
                <input type="text" id="B" name="B" placeholder="No. of Students" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['B']) ? $_POST['B'] : '' ?>"><br>
                <label for="C">No. of School Days:</label>
                <input type="text" id="C" name="C" placeholder="No. of School Days" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['C']) ? $_POST['C'] : '' ?>"><br>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Calculate</button>
              </form>
              <h4>
                <?php
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    // Retrieve user input values for D, B, and C
                    $D = isset($_POST['D']) ? $_POST['D'] : 0;
                    $B = isset($_POST['B']) ? $_POST['B'] : 0;
                    $C = isset($_POST['C']) ? $_POST['C'] : 0;

                    // Ensure the inputs are numeric
                    if (is_numeric($D) && is_numeric($B) && is_numeric($C)) {
                        // Check if B and C are not zero to avoid division by zero error
                        if ($B != 0 && $C != 0) {
                            // Calculate A = D / (B * C)
                            $A = $D / ($B * $C);
                            // Convert to percentage
                            $percentage = $A * 100;
                            echo "Result: A = " . $A . " or  " . $percentage . "%";
                        } else {
                            echo "Error: Division by zero";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "Please enter numeric values for D, B, and C";
                    }
                }
                ?>
              </h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<?php include 'includes/scripts.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>

This is the code I edited:
<?php include 'includes/session.php'; ?>
<?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

  <?php include 'includes/navbar.php'; ?>
  <?php include 'includes/menubar.php'; ?>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Calculator
      </h1>
    </section>
    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-body">
              <form method="post">
                <label for="course">Select Course:</label>
                <select id="course" name="course">
                  <option value="">Select Course</option>
                  <?php
                  // Fetch courses from your database and populate the dropdown menu
                  // Assuming you have a database connection already established
                  $query = "SELECT * FROM position_college"; // Modify this query according to your database schema
                  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                  if ($result) {
                      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                          echo "<option value='" . $row['description_college'] . "</option>";
                      }
                  }
                  ?>
                </select><br>
                <label for="D">No. of Attendance:</label>
                <input type="text" id="D" name="D" placeholder="No. of Attendance" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['D']) ? $_POST['D'] : '' ?>"><br>
                <label for="B">No. of Students:</label>
                <input type="text" id="B" name="B" placeholder="No. of Students" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['B']) ? $_POST['B'] : '' ?>"><br>
                <label for="C">No. of School Days:</label>
                <input type="text" id="C" name="C" placeholder="No. of School Days" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['C']) ? $_POST['C'] : '' ?>"><br>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Calculate</button>
              </form>
              <h4>
                <?php
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    // Retrieve user input values for D, B, C, and the selected course
                    $D = isset($_POST['D']) ? $_POST['D'] : 0;
                    $B = isset($_POST['B']) ? $_POST['B'] : 0;
                    $C = isset($_POST['C']) ? $_POST['C'] : 0;
                    $selected_course = isset($_POST['course']) ? $_POST['course'] : 0;

                    // Ensure the inputs are numeric
                    if (is_numeric($D) && is_numeric($B) && is_numeric($C) && $selected_course) {
                        // Check if B and C are not zero to avoid division by zero error
                        if ($B != 0 && $C != 0) {
                            // Calculate A = D / (B * C)
                            $A = $D / ($B * $C);
                            // Convert to percentage
                            $percentage = $A * 100;
                            echo "Result: A = " . $A . " or  " . $percentage . "%";
                        } else {
                            echo "Error: Division by zero";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "Please enter numeric values for D, B, C, and select a course";
                    }
                }
                ?>
              </h4>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<?php include 'includes/scripts.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>

But this code doesn't work and it doesn't seem to provide result the I wanted it to give. These are the tables in the database



And what is the result you wanted to get? What result did you get instead? Can you provide sample source data too? We can't easily tell you what to do based on data we've never seen. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your  issue. You can [edit] your question.

If your users will be typing in values for B, C, and D, you don't need PHP for this. Javascript will do. If you want to retrieve those values from the database, however, you need to edit your question and tell us how you are tracking attendance and school days. I'm assuming that you're using attendance and schedules tables for that, but please be more specific - show us the structure for those two tables, and give us some sample data, which would show what you want the end result to be.
